# Getting the Current User

Tags: php, users

I am trying to use information about the current user in a plugin that I am designing and I have seen people go about it in several different ways.

### My Way

This way seems to work, but am I missing something?

```
global $current_user;

// Use information
echo "User ID: " . $current_user->user_id;
echo "User First Name: " . $current_user->first_name;
```

I have seen some people call the function `get_currentuserinfo()` on the next line after declaring the global variable $current_user.  However, this seems to work without that call - so is it necessary?

Also, there is the function `wp_get_current_user()` - what is the difference between this and `get_currentuserinfo()`?

I have also seen people use a global variable called `$profileuser` and use `get_user_to_edit()` in order to set it to the user object.  Is there some benefit to this?

I have also seen people refer directly to the `$user_ID` global variable in addition to using the `$current_user`.  Why wouldn't they just use `$current_user->ID`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Call the function `get_currentuserinfo()` on the next line after declaring the global variable `$current_user`
2. What is the difference between `wp_get_current_user()` and `get_currentuserinfo()`?

Below is a snippet:

```
function wp_get_current_user() {

    global $current_user;

    get_currentuserinfo();

    return $current_user;
}
```

I think the source code answers your first two questions, right?

Remember that `wp_get_current_user()` is defined in `wp-includes/pluggable.php` so it can be overridden.

Also, it is safe to stick with `global $current_user` this is because WordPress calls `wp_get_current_user()` during initialization.

Specifically, wp-settings.php -> new WP -> WP->init() ->  wp_get_current_user

---

The usage of `$profileuser`, this global variable is only available when you are editing a user (user-edit.php) and the data will be thereof.

The last one questions I don't really know how to answer so I'll leave to others.

Hope you don't mind.

Comment: FYI: `get_currentuserinfo()` is deprecated as at WordPress 4.5.0. Use `wp_get_current_user()` instead.