# Current User Seeing Another Logged In User Info

Tags: users, login

Having a strange issue where I am checking for the current user by using the `wp_get_current_user` command and occasionally, users have reported to seeing the information for another user.  Should I be checking for the current user a different way?  This is scary because the information that I am displaying for the users is sensitive and I need the system to only show the current user and not another user that is also logged in.

UPDATE:
Attached code...

```
function ssm_dashboard()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo '<h3>Parent Dashboard</h3>';

    if (current_user_can(SSM_CAPS_APPROVED_USER))
    {
        $ssmuser = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT id, last_name, first_name FROM " . $wpdb->prefix.SSM_USER_TABLE . " WHERE user_id_1=" . $user->ID, ARRAY_A); 
        echo 'Welcome ' . $ssmuser['first_name'] . ' ' . $ssmuser['last_name'];
    }
}
```

So, the code snippet is a widget I created for my plugin that shows a user's dashboard.  What is supposed to happen is that once a user logs in, the widget gets the current user's ID, then looks up their account in my table (wp_ssm_user) and returns the row that matches the wp_user->ID and is displayed on the dashboard.  Problem is, some users are reporting that when they log in and perform certain functions (I'm awaiting a reply as to which function in particular), they are redirected to the dashboard where a different user's information is displayed.

Comment: Post all of the relevant code please.

Comment: There is no redirect at all in that code so I am leaning toward thinking the real issue is elsewhere. I'll wait for the additional information before speculating more. How is that function called/hooked?

Comment: It's a shortcode.  I add the shortcode to a page.  And you are correct as far as the redirect.  The redirect happens from another shortcode.  Not sure it is a valid point, but I did find [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90100/getting-the-current-user?rq=1) which @Jesse answered with the point of using global $current_user when trying to get the current user information.  I was using the wp_get_current_user() method.  Not sure if it makes a difference but I am testing it currently.